# JavaScript : Save/Load array to a file?

Tags: javascript

(This is for local use only, using WAMP)
I have some Javascript's that create a array containing some string and objects.
I would like to save this array to a file, so that i can later load it into another JavaScript.

I have seached Google all night, but can seem to find any way of doing this :(

Comment: Use the browser's localstorage if you don't need an actual file but only to store/load data on different pages (different scripts) of your site.

Comment: @Bergi is absolutely correct on this one, localStorage is what you want and need.

Comment: localstorage is good but what if he needs the data in other browser?

Answer (score 2):

use `JSON.stringify(myarray)` first, then you can use AJAX to send the data to the server. You can use `file_put_contents`(php) to save the file to the server's disk...you can retrieve the array and use it later using JSON.parse(array_from_file);

Comment: do not worry, there are plenty of tutorials in the net. heres one good example http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ :-) Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

You can send json to php server and from there you can write it to a json file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this locally, you can constrain yourself to Chrome and use the HTML5 FileWriter API. Here's a [guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to get you started. Also, you can check on the [status of the browser compatibility matrix here](http://caniuse.com/#search=filewriter).

Also, you might want to consider using the HTML5 LocalStorage or SessionStorage API's as well.

There's also the [HTML5 FileSystem API polyfill that uses IndexedDB](https://github.com/ebidel/idb.filesystem.js).